# How to solve this equation for x?

Tags: analysis, logarithms

can somebody help me with this?

$$2=2^{1-x}+(\frac{2}{3})^{1-x}$$

I guess I somehow have to isolate this 1-x term and then use the ln. But I don't get how..

Thanks in advance!

Mostly irrelevant side quest: I have the (paid) Wolframalpha app which is supposed to show step-by-step solutions. However, 9/10 times it says "step-by-step solution unavailable". Anyone knows what is up with that?

Comment: By inspection  $x=1,2$ are two solutions.

Comment: Does $x \in \mathbb{Z} , \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ ? If $x \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $2 = 2^{1-x}+\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{1-x} \iff 2^{x}=1+3^{x-1}$, for $x\le 0$, $2^x \le 1 < 1 + 3^{x-1}$. Also $2^x = 1+3^{x-1} > 3^{x-1} $, this gives an upperbound on $x$, which is $x<3$, hence the only possible solutions are $x=1,2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that

$$f(x)=2^{1-x}+\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{1-x} \implies f'(x)=-2^{1-x}\log 2+\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{1-x}\log \frac32 \\\implies f''(x)=2^{1-x}\log^2 2+\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{1-x}\log^2 \frac32>0 $$

therefore $f(x)$ is convex and $f(x)=2$ has at most $2$ solutions which are by inspection $x=1$ and $x=2$.